# my Sprite isnt drawing on screen XNA

Tags: c#, xna, draw

What am i missing here

Sprite Class

```
    private Texture2D m_tex;
    public Rectangle rect;
    private bool m_travellingRight;
    private int x_pos;

    //constructor
    public LightSaber(Texture2D tex, int xpos, int ypos)
    {
        m_tex = tex;
        rect = new Rectangle(xpos, ypos, m_tex.Width, m_tex.Height);
        m_travellingRight = true;
    }

    public void drawme(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        if (m_travellingRight)
            sb.Draw(m_tex, rect, Color.White);
        else
            sb.Draw(m_tex, rect, null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally, 0);
    }

    public void updateme(GamePadState pad)
    {
        x_pos = rect.X;
        if (pad.ThumbSticks.Left.X < 0 && x_pos > 0)
        {
            m_travellingRight = false;
            rect.X -= 4;
        }
        else if (pad.ThumbSticks.Left.X > 0 && x_pos < 800 - rect.Width)
        {
            m_travellingRight = true;
            rect.X += 4;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Game1:

```
LightSaber lightSaber;

lightSaber = new LightSaber(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures\\Lightsaber"), 300, 500);

lightSaber.drawme(spriteBatch);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: its C# yes haha my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I miss a lot of code in the Game1.class, it would be nice to see the whole class to look if you're missing anything.

So for now, I'll give you a few tips:

- I don't see any spritebatch.begin() or spritebatch.End() in the game1 class, since it's so shortened up, those should be required in order to draw anything.
- You can also try putting a breakpoint on the moment it should be drawing the texture. and check if it actually does draw it, or at least can reach it.
- Another possibility, it does draw the sprite, but it's location is out of bounds, (outside the game window), I prefer putting the position on 0 untill I'm sure it can draw the texture
- Also, be aware when you're using statements without braces. Because without them, it can only read one line of code after the statement. if you add a new line or comment out the statement, then you'll get unexpected behaviour. (I had that mistake made before).

That's it for now, hope this helps